# Gradle 5 & Java 11 build error: Why does Gradle think I'm using Java 10?

Tags: java, ubuntu, gradle

I'm unable to build my project using Java 11 and Gradle 5.  I receive the following error trying to build:

```
$ gradle clean build
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 10 (1.10)'.
```

Why does Gradle think I'm using JDK 10?  My `$JAVA_HOME` is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/`, which is the Linux OpenJDK build for Java 11 (found here https://jdk.java.net/11/).  I'm using Gradle 5, but this error also occurred using 4.10.2.

Below are the relevant parts of my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 11
```

I've also tried using `1.11` for source compatibility but this also fails with the same error.

Comment: Not sure that Gradle supports Java 11 yet. Others have seen this error.

Comment: Their Gradle 5 release notes say they officially support Java 11 now: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases/tag/v5.0.0

Comment: Did some more digging, the problem I'm experiencing is unique to Ubuntu.  Ubuntu actually provides JDK10 disguised as JDK11, no clue why:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-lts/+bug/1796027  Not sure why anyone would think that's a good idea.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037646/why-is-openjdk-10-packaged-as-openjdk-11

Comment: I faced a similar issue, but that was resolved when gradle picked up correct version of JDK (11 instead of 1.8) using JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME can be set easily following this https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was unique to Ubuntu 18.  The "JDK11" that is in `apt` is actually JDK10 with backported JDK11 security updates.  That's fairly confusing, so there is [an open bug report with Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-lts/+bug/1796027).  See also [this post on the AskUbuntu stack exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037646/why-is-openjdk-10-packaged-as-openjdk-11).

To resolve the issue you have to manually set your system to use an actual JDK11.  I did something similar to [this guide](https://dzone.com/articles/installing-openjdk-11-on-ubuntu-1804-for-real) to fix it.